# Cjuiautocomplete on a CActiveForm in a Create method in yii

Tags: php, jquery, yii, autocomplete

Brief explanation of what I'm trying to do.  I am trying to implement an autocomplete in a create form.  I know this seems strange but the table that is being added to is a list of "out of office" people.  So my autocomplete looks up user names on the user table, my actionCreate, can use the Last, First to look up the user id and add them to the table.  This all works fine.  I can see the autocomplete.  The issue is this:

When I type in a partial name the list of names pops up but i cannot select from them. Whenever I mouse over the drop down the list disapears, the same thing happens when I press "down".

Here is the code for the form.  I have tried multiple different ways of implementing an autocomplete and so far this one works the best I am just unable to get the autocomplete to fill the field.

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'away-mentor-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); ?>

<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo "Last-Name, First-Name"; ?><br/>

    <?php
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
        'name'=>'name_search',
        'value'=>$model->name_search,

        'source'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('/AwayMentor/FindUserName'),// <- path to controller which returns dynamic data
        // additional javascript options for the autocomplete plugin
        'options'=>array(
            'minLength'=>'1', // min chars to start search
            'select'=>'js:function(event, ui) { console.log(ui.item.id +":"+ui.item.value); }'
        ),
        'htmlOptions'=>array(
            'id'=>'name_search',
            'rel'=>'val',
        ),
    ));
    echo $form->error($model,'name_search'); ?>
</div>


<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Comment: what is output of `Yii::app()->createUrl('/AwayMentor/FindUserName')`.

Comment: The names from the table user.  User model has a function that returns the "last, first" from its table which find user name searches on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Something Like: -

```
     <?php

    $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
        'name' => 'name_search',
        'value' => $model->name_search,
        'source' => Yii::app()->createUrl('/AwayMentor/FindUserName'), // <- path to controller which returns dynamic data
        // additional javascript options for the autocomplete plugin
        'options' => array(
            'minLength' => '1', // min chars to start search
            'select' => "js: function(event, data) {
                                                $('#name_search').val(data.item.value);
                                                $(this).data('id',data.item.id); 
                                                return false;
                                                            }",
            'focus' => "js: function(event,data){
                                                    $(this).val(data.item.value);  
                                                    return false;
                                                        }"
        ),
        'htmlOptions' => array(
            'id' => 'name_search',
            'rel' => 'val',
        ),
    ));
    echo $form->error($model, 'name_search');


  Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('autocomplete', "
  jQuery('#name_search').data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $('<li></li>')
      .data('item.autocomplete', item)
      .append('<a>' + item.value + '<br><i>' + item.id + '</i></a>')
      .appendTo(ul);
  };",
  CClientScript::POS_READY
);
?>
```

Comment: I did, Still does the same thing.  Your code DOES add the user_id # to the end of the name in the auto complete drop down but it still disappears on hover/pressing down. .....AAAAANNNDDD I just fixed it. there was a bit of code in there generated by yii or ... something $this->endwidget(); I just noticed it after many days of trying figure this out.  Just commented it out and it works now perfectly.

Comment: Never mind that didn't fix it, that broke it, I didn't refresh the page.  I added a partially working code(fills but I can't get the data from it) that adds another field box and now the top box works perfectly.  I'm getting so confused.

Comment: Ok I finally fixed it I think, adding  <html lang="en">

    <body>
    <form action="AwayMentor/Create">


        <script>
            $( "#name_search" ).autocomplete({
                source: './FindUserName'
            });
        </script>

    </form>
    </body>
    </html> after <php? $this->endwidget();?> now allows me to select form the drop down bar with your code as well.  thank you So much.